# Cross-Origin Request Blocked in web api

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web Api project (name TestApi).

When I Debug this Project, Then I'm Getting the JSON data when I enter this URL **"http://localhost:31310/api/Authors"**

Now I want to call this api method from another MVC project (name as : callTestApi), using Jquery, I have written this line of code.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: 'http://localhost:31310/api/Authors/',
            success: function (data) {
                var getAll = data;
                alert(data[0].Name)
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('Error in getting result');
            }
        });
```

I have enabled the CORS in my *TestApi* project.
see here

```
 [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class AuthorsController : ApiController
    {
        private TestWebApiContext db = new TestWebApiContext();

        // GET: api/Authors
        public IQueryable<Author> GetAuthors()
        {
            return db.Authors;
        }
   }
```

I have added CORS in my project (TestApi), using this command

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors -Version 5.2.2
```

I have enable it Webapiconfig file

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.EnableCors();
        }
```

Comment: Try listing out the headers instead of using a wildcard

Comment: Can you show us what is the error your getting?

Answer (score 2):

try to add this in your API's web.config after `<System.WebServer>` tag

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

maybe  `config.EnableCors();` is not enough.

Comment: Anyway this exposes you to XSS attacks, as explained [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)).

Answer (score 0):

try:
`[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]`
I think ***localhost*** is not allowed.